# apache2 can not set REMOTE_ADDR or any other var as header

Tags: linux, apache2, headers

i trying to setup apache as a reverse proxy and i need to add e.g. the REMOTE_ADDR and some other values as an header (required by the backend), for some reason always "null" is set.

Ignoring the proxy part, setting a header should be fairly simple and is working without any problems:
Header set x-remote test

So mod_headers should work, otherwise the header wouldn't be set?!

trying to set the REMOTE_ADDR or any other VAR (SERVER_NAME, HTTP_HOST), just sets "null"

Header set x-remote %{REMOTE_ADDR}e

The Syntax seems right and no error gets logged/shown anywhere.
redis-/enable mod_headers didn't work neither reinstalling everything...
Running on SLES 15SP4

Comment: The problem ist not to set a header for the proxy but with the value being always null

Answer (score 0):

Adding headers to the requests sent by Apache mod_proxy to a backend server requires the [`ProxyAddHeaders`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyaddheaders) directive rather than mod_headers `Header set`.

Comment: I know i've to set the headers via RequestHeader which is also working fine with a fixed string but not any server/env var.
REMOTE_ADDR, SERVER_NAME, etc. is always null when set via header, if used e.g. in mod_rewrite it has a value

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add headers to the *request* that is being sent to the backend server (e.g. make the backend server think the header was sent by the client), you need to use **RequestHeader** directive. The **Header** directive is used to set *response* headers (i.e. what the client receives in the reply).

See the differences here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header